# redux-form isDirty not reset after successful submit

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I'm using `isDirty` to check if form values have entered (and disable other things based on that).

```
import { isDirty } from 'redux-form';
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isFormDirty: isDirty('myform')(state)
});
```

This works great as in the buttons I want to disable get disabled when a form value is changed. They also get enabled when I dispatch the `reset` redux-form action creator.

However, succesfully submitting the form does not clear dirty state. The buttons I have disabled by the `isDirty` check remain disabled.

Do I need to manually tell redux-form that the form is now pristine? And how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I now worked around this by dispatching the `initialize` action from my action creator that is passed as `onSubmit` to the form.

```
import { getFormInitialValues, initialize } from 'redux-form';
export function saveData(data) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => { // this is redux-thunk
    api.saveSomething(data).then(newData => {
      // dispatch some actions
      dispatch(someAction(newData));
      let activeFormValues = getFormInitialValues('myform')(getState());
      if (activeFormValues.id === data.id) { // Reset the form with new initialValues
        dispatch(initialize('myform', newData, false, { keepSubmitSucceeded: true }));
      }
    });
  };
}
```